# Best practice to get related list of object to another object in Django

Tags: python, django

I have such fucntion. It is rather simple and all it does is it gets some forum thread and comments related to it.

```
def thread_detail(req, id):
    thread = Thread.objects.get(pk=id)
    comments = thread.comment_set.all()
    return render(req, 'threads/thread.html', {'thread': thread, 'comments': comments})
```

But I am not sure that this is the way you should do it in Django. Is it better to use DetailView or mix of SingleObjectMixin and ListView as [shown in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview)?

Comment: it looks alright to me, in terms of DB/ORM query to get the related comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a class based view if you don't want to. The advantage of your function based view is that it is very straight forward and easy to understand. The advantage of the class based view is that you get to take advantage of other functionality in the view, e.g. pagination.

Personally, I think your function based view is much easier to understand than the example in the docs using `SingleObjectMixin` and `ListView`.

I would recommend that you use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), so that you show a 404 page to users when a thread with that primary key does not exist.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, pk=id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most often I see it more like a personal preference.

From the book of good practices in django. **'TWO SCOOPS OF DJANGO 1.8'**

> The simplicity of FBVs comes at the expense of code reuse: FBVs
>   don’t have the same ability to inherit from superclasses the way that
>   CBVs do. ey do have the advantage of being more obviously functional
>   in nature, which lends itself to a number of interesting strategies

I agree with @Alasdair, your function based view is easier to understand.

I only change it in the code:

```
def thread_detail(req, id):
    thread_qs = Thread.objects.filter(pk=id).prefetch_related('comment_set')
    if not thread_qs:
        raise Http404
    else:
        thread = thread_qs[0]
        return render(req, 'threads/thread.html', {'thread': thread})
```

and in the html, just iterator on thread comments:

```
{%for comment in thread.comment_set.all %}
    {{comment}}
{%endfor%}
```

For since it is good practice, I think it would also help improve performance.

Comment: Using prefetch related won't speed up the code in this case, because we are viewing a single thread. It is faster when we have a queryset of many threads, and want to fetch all the related comments at once.